# Is changing SpriteBatch projection matrix inside begin...end a good idea?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a list of game objects that I want to render in libgdx 2D.

In my setup I have two different cameras, one that matches the pixel resolution exactly (for drawing tiled background and fonts) and one that matches the gameboard with a typical viewport of (-0.1, -0.1, 1.2, 1.5).

Now I would like each game object in the list to decide for themselves which camera to use when rendering, which means that the projection matrices for the SpriteBatch may change several times inside the SpriteBatch.begin()...end().

One other solution would be to have two SpriteBatches active at the same time and make the game objects select which spritebatch to render to, and then call End() on them after rendering is finished. Some other questions and posts I've found on the Internets suggest that multiple active SpriteBatches is not a good idea.

What are the pros and cons of these solutions? Is there a better one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design wise, thats awful!

I usually have 2 cameras aswell. One for the game objects with low values (12x8 or 15x10), and one for the HUD (attack button, stats, etc) with high values (pixel perfect of my test device). I first draw the game objects, finish the batch, and then I draw the HUD. Just 2 draws. But:

[SpriteBatch#setProjectionMatrix](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#setProjectionMatrix%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4%29)
"If this is called inside a Batch.begin()/Batch.end() block, the current batch is flushed to the gpu."

If you set the projection matrix several times inside your render code, that will trigger a lot of batch flushes and negatively (and greatly) affect your performance.

Comment: OK, thanks for clearing that up. Somewhat embarrassing not to find the  linked info, though... :) How about the other suggested solution with two simulatenous SpriteBatches, do you think? It feels risky, how will they interlace, for instance? The one that is ended first ends up at the bottom, below all the contents of the other batch...?

Comment: Yep,the one that ends first will be drawn first. I suggest you to group all the draws  of one camera and then the ones of the other. (1.Tiled Background, 2.-Objects 3.-Hud). Or better yet, unify the units of them all, and just use one.